# how to identify first record in a column pysaprk

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe with many columns
So I have to identigy first record of a column and assign it one value and for others assign another value
i.e

```
if df[price].first_record = df[amt]
else

df[price] = df[amt]+df[delivery_charges]
```

how do I identify the first record in a column/dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way:

```
window = Window.orderBy('Id')
df.withColumn('row',f.row_number().over(window)).withColumn('price',f.when(f.col('row')==1,f.col('amt')).otherwise(f.col('amt')+f.col('delivery_charges'))).show()
```